# How to find out the lowest value with a generic method?

Tags: java, arrays, generics, arraylist

I am trying to resolve an excercise about finding out the lowest value in array using loop. The excercise is about generics. But i have a hard to find out the solution. For an array of string i will use " **if (minimum.compareTo(list[i]) > 0)**  ". I am stuck in how to do this with an array of integer. Any hint or help is very appreciate.

There is my code:

```
 public class Excercise {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            //Create an array 
            Integer[] intArray = { new Integer(45), new Integer(2), new Integer(6), new Integer(15) };
            //print the lowest value
            System.out.print(min(intArray));
            // min(intArray);
        }

        public static <E extends Comparable<E>> E min(E[] list) {
            E minValue = list[0];
            for(int i = 1; i < list.length; i++) {
            if(minValue.compareTo(list[i]) {    <-- i get an error her
                minValue = list[i];


         return minValue;
   }
}
```

Comment: You need one of the number subclasses to compare (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberclasses.html) perhaps a cast will help?

Comment: `Collections.min(Arrays.asList(yourArray))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`compareTo` doesn't return a `boolean`, so you can't use it as a condition of your `if` clause.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29

Instead, it an returns int.  If the result is above zero, that means the first term is greater.  If it is below, it is lesser.

So  use `if(minValue.compareTo(list[i])>0))` instead.

There are other bugs in the code (mostly typos).  I will leave those to you.

Comment: it dosen't work neither > 0 nor < 0 !!- What do you mean other bugs? for me it seems everything is alright exempt from what i asked!

Comment: it works fine.  I tried and ran your code.  You'll need to fix the other syntax errors of course.

Comment: I got it (but it's better with > 0). thanks for your help and your advice.

Answer (score 2):

because compareTo() method will return integer value 
change

```
if(minValue.compareTo(list[i]) {
```

to

```
if(minValue.compareTo(list[i]) > 0) {
```

Comment: i get this: The operator > is undefined for the argument type(s) E, int .. when i used: if(minValue.compareTo(list[i] > 0) ..i don't understand

Answer (score 1):

The proper method should be as follows:

```
public static <E extends Comparable<E>> E min(E[] list) {
     E minValue = list[0];
     for(int i = 1; i < list.length; i++) {
         if( minValue.compareTo(list[i]) > 0) { //compareTo always returns an int
             minValue = list[i];
         }
     }
     return minValue; // returs the minimum after checking all the array
}
```

Comment: i get this: The operator > is undefined for the argument type(s) E, int .. when i used: if(minValue.compareTo(list[i] > 0) ..i don't understand

Comment: Your are missing a ')', I'll edit the answer to make it clearer